Can I bypass/ eliminate the comments field on an approval process?
I am working on an approval process for a hiring manager. I don't want the manager to have the capability to enter comments/ notes when approving due to possible liability issues. Is there a way I can hide the comments field that populates, or make it read-only, or something else to prevent it from being text capable?
